# Filepicker.io on iOS doesn't allow picking from Picasa

Tags: filepicker.io

However an image can be *saved* to Picasa.  Is this a limitation of Picasa, or a bug in the SDK?  Thanks.

Comment: Looking into it right now, but just to check, have you tried to scroll the listing to see more options? It's "below the fold" so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liyan is right, the Picasa option was "below the fold" (*slaps forehead*)